# I want to replace my renault clio engine F8Q by another one of toyota

Tags: engine, toyota, renault

I want to change the engine of my RENAULT CLIO II 1.9D. This engine was broken when the stone hit the bottom of the engine (carter) then the engine stopped to work because there was any oil.

So I wish to change this engine to another one of another type, say TOYOTA for example. I would like to know if this could go well if I make this change( Renault diesel  bya Toyota essence).

Thank You.

Answer (score 7):

Changing to a completely different engine is quite difficult, and not recommended for beginners - there are a lot of factors to be considered, particularly with regards to compatibility of parts - e.g. which gearbox would you use, which clutch, driveshafts etc, and will the whole assembly fit, how will you make the new mounts, and so on.

Unless you have a particular reason for choosing to fit a particular engine, I'd recommend a like-for-like replacement, i.e. another Clio engine. This will also save a lot of paperwork (depending on where you are - insurance companies, licensing authorities etc often need to be notified, and I believe that some countries won't allow it at all)